# React-native get stuck at Dependency Graph

Tags: react-native

I try to start with react-native, I've installed everything and got to phase where I have RSoD on my phone which is telling me to run server.
When i run `react-native start` lot of things runs, but then it gets stuck at `<END>   Building Dependency Graph` and I have no idea what to do with it. So, how can I make it continue?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before trying to run `react-native start`?

Comment: I don't see any relation between those commands, but I tried it anyway. Nothing changed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if the relation was not clear. `npm install` installs the dependencies that your application has defined in your `package.json`, so I thought that might have been a cause for your problems. Doesn't seem like that was it though.. I just re-ran this and realized it's actually supposed to stop at "building dependency graph", once you get this message, try reloading the app on your phone and it should fetch the latest bundle, and it should work.

Comment: As Alexander stated, when you get the `<END>   Building Dependency Graph` message, it means You're good to go, everything works as it should and your enviroment is ready.

Comment: Running `react-native link` before start works for me.

Comment: Close Chrome debugger (http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/) if it is still open

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The building of the dependency graph may take some time (ca 1-3 minutes). The progress is shown by a percentage behind this line; if the percentage disappears you are ready. The `react-native start` command doesn't terminate, as it continues to serve the transformed source code with the react native packager. Your app will make requests to the provided url if you have the default settings.

Answer (score 22):

One reason the "Building Dependency Graph" step might hang may be due to that there is a (Chrome) debugger session running from a previous session or another project. One way to fix that is to completely quit out of Xcode, your terminal, and Chrome and then restart everything. I'm sure there is a better way to fix the issue, but that is what worked for me.

Comment: I disabled remote JS debugging in the iOS simulator and it came right back to life.

Comment: A completely different answer solving problem than the accepted answer. Irony. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: in my case, `building dependency graph` has done. But stuck after that. How to solve that?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, that it ended there and even refreshing the simulator didn't make the packager to go on. Then I figured it out: I was still connected to the Internet via a VPN, so the simulator couldn't connect to the packager. Simply closing the VPN solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. In my case I had proxy settings enabled on the Android emulator because I was debugging a web API issue the day before. And today I spent some time figuring out what's wrong until I saw your comment and figured I still had proxy turned on but Charles was not running.

Comment: Many times ago I had been set a proxy for my mac and after many search finally I found the proxy causes the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I opened

> Command prompt

as Administrator
reached to the app location and enter

```
react-native start
```

it goes till Loading dependency graph, done.
Then I remained it open and open another command prompt as Administrator 
go to the app location and entered

```
react-native run-android
```

and its worked....

In mac open **Terminal** instead of **Command prompt** and rest is same.

Peace ...

Answer (score 4):

After the command `react-native run-android` worked for me. I just waited library installings, after that it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
 sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
 sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000
```

you can try this bunch of line in your terminal. Just increase the max_user_watches number and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the ios sub-directory and run a pod install:

```
cd ./ios
pod install
```

Then, in the main project directory, run react-native run-ios.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had proxy settings enabled on the Android emulator. I solved the problem by disabling the proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

Restart everything, restart your laptop, then run the build command again, everything will work again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be caused if you changed the jsCodeLocation to use a static bundle in AppDelegate.m for a release build and didn't change it back to the local settings.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#3-configure-app-to-use-static-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Shake your device, on the menu, select enable live reload and enable hot reload

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the reasons,
Try with uninstalling the app from device/emulator/simulator and re-run the command

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both your device and your laptop are on the same wi-fi network. My phone was on LTE and my laptop was on my regular wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below actions if you created your app with `react-native init YOUR_APP_NAME` and are using android studio with AVD simulator.

1. Make sure that your network is not firewall protected. If it is, the wifi in your simulator does not work (at least for me). Try using other networks / mobile hotspot.
2. Make sure that the simulator is using android version pie with API level 28 as mentioned in the react-native documentation.
3. Open android studio and run the simulator.
4. If you are in windows platform, run the code using `react-native run-android` instead of `npm start`
5. If you are on mac, run the code using `react-native run-ios` instead of `npm start`
6. Wait for few minutes. The application should open in your simulator after loading the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to Settings > Apps and Notifications > Show All Apps > `The app im trying to start` and then the three dots in the top right corner and uninstall for all users. Then i ran `yarn run android` again

Answer (score 0):

I also met with the same issue, then I used a version when creating the app in react CLI..

```
react-native init project_name --version x.xx.x
eg:react-native init project_name --version 0.49.0

or u can overcome this by installing a different nodeJS version
```

Answer (score 0):

I am somehow able to get this to work by going into a fresh chrome instance and going to either "localhost:8081" or *your local ip*:8081... somehow after about a minute or three it snaps out of it.

Answer (score 0):

if you on Ubuntu type in terminal

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000
watchman shutdown-server
```

then type in terminal react-native start

Answer (score 0):

Add a line of code given below, in your android/app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.0'
```

along with gradle version 5.5.1 in gradle-wrapper.properties as:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem on Mac, tried downgrading the Node version but it didn't help.

I was testing on Android and executing the below command helped move forward:

`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting this on my CI servers (well, running `react-native bundle`). My resolution was to manually add the flag `--max-workers 4`.

I speculate this is because CI servers do funky things with virtualisation of CPUs which affects the defaults detected in react-native.