# React Native app works when run from Xcode, but crashes when run with 'react-native run-ios'

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, emulation

Today my React Native app crashed when I ran it using `react-native run-ios`. The default splash screen would appear, but then it would crash and I would just see the emulator homescreen with my app's icon on the desktop. The Terminal is hanging on "Loading dependency graph, done". It worked fine yesterday, and I haven't changed anything since then. When I run it from Xcode, it works. I've tried all the suggestions at the following four links for getting it to run with `react-native run-ios` without success: [link1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16798) [link2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19121) [link3](https://medium.com/@TETRA2000/react-native-bundle-hangs-during-loading-dependency-graph-f40bc7347125) and [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406567/react-native-get-stuck-at-dependency-graph)

**My Question Is:**

Does anyone know why it would work from Xcode and not from `react-native run-ios`? And does anyone know why it would suddenly start crashing when it worked fine before?

Comment: Have you updated your Mac?

Comment: Yep :) Everything is up to date, including React Native and Xcode

Comment: Did you manage to figure out the solutions?

Comment: @AnnieTanno not yet. I've been running it from XCode instead, because after a few weeks of trying, I couldn't get it to work. Are you facing the same problem? One of my co-workers is too.

Answer (score 2):

Some things you can try

Check iOS simulator log after crash:

```
cat /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/REPLACE_HERE/system.log
```

In my case I had

```
Class RCTBlobManager is implemented in both ... One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

And

```
assertion failed: 19D76 17F61: libxpc.dylib
```

It did work from xcode 11.5 / iOS 13, but did not work from react-native. I found out that it bug can be tracked by launching app after stopping debug from xcode, if it launches after stop debug then it also worked from react-native

```
react-native run-ios
```

In Podfile I have enabled

```
use_frameworks
```

Got rid of these by doing 2 things:

[image]

Hope at least someone facing these problems this post would give at least some hints